Slim/Twig route not found (404) when trying to duplicate an invoice via AJAX
I'm working on a Laravel application for invoice management. I'm trying to implement a feature to duplicate invoices, but I'm encountering a 404 "Resource not found" error when making the AJAX call.
Here's my route definition:
$this-\>group('/electronic-invoices', function () use ($container) {
$this-\>post('/duplicate/{id}', InvoiceOutController::class . ':duplicate')-\>setName('duplicate_electronic_invoices');
});

Here's the relevant part of my InvoiceOutController:
public function duplicate($request, $response, $args)
{
    $this->logger->info('Metodo duplicate chiamato con ID: ' . $args['id']);
    $invoiceId = $args['id'];
    $originalInvoice = ElectronicInvoice::find($invoiceId);

    if (!$originalInvoice) {
        return $response->withJson(['success' => false, 'message' => 'Fattura non trovata'], 404);
    }

    try {
        DB::beginTransaction();

        $newInvoice = $originalInvoice->replicate();
        $newInvoice->invoice_number = $this->generateNewInvoiceNumber();
        $newInvoice->date = date('Y-m-d');
        $newInvoice->save();

        foreach ($originalInvoice->items as $item) {
            $newItem = $item->replicate();
            $newItem->invoice_id = $newInvoice->id;
            $newItem->save();
        }

        DB::commit();

        return $response->withJson(['success' => true, 'message' => 'Fattura duplicata con successo'], 200);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        DB::rollBack();
        return $response->withJson(['success' => false, 'message' => 'Errore durante la duplicazione: ' . $e->getMessage()], 500);
    }
}

And here's my JavaScript code that makes the AJAX call:
$('#invoices').on('click', '.duplicate-invoice', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var invoiceId = $(this).data('id');
    $('#duplicateConfirmModal').modal('show');
    
    $('#confirmDuplicate').off('click').on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '{{ path_for('duplicate_electronic_invoices', {'id': ''}) }}' + invoiceId,
            method: 'POST',
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    alert(response.message);
                    table.ajax.reload();
                } else {
                    alert('Errore: ' + response.message);
                }
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Si è verificato un errore durante la duplicazione.');
            }
        });
        $('#duplicateConfirmModal').modal('hide');
    });
});

When I try to duplicate an invoice, I get the following error:
[Fri Aug  2 17:22:41 2024] ::1:54565 [404]: /electronic-invoices/duplicate/51584
{"error":"Risorsa non trovata."}

I've tried the following:

Verified that the route is in the correct group
Checked for any typos in the route name
Added logging statements to all middleware, but none of them seem to be triggered
Verified that the controller and method exist and are accessible
Checked for any global middleware that might be interfering

What could be causing this 404 error, and how can I resolve it to make the invoice duplication work correctly?

Why do you have -\> in your route definition code instead of -> is that just typo in question?
